# Android soundpool rate range?

Tags: android, frequency, soundpool

Android's `soundpool.play` [documentation][1] says "*The playback rate allows the application to vary the playback rate (pitch) of the sound. A value of 1.0 means play back at the original frequency. A value of 2.0 means play back twice as fast, and a value of 0.5 means playback at half speed.*".

However, when I set the rate to 1.49f, I hear silence. 1.485f renders correctly (it's ogg file). Is this specific to my handset, is the documentation wrong, or am I being foolish in some other way?

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play(int, float, float, int, int, float)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sort of new at this, but I'm pretty sure it needs to be 0.5f, 1f, or 1.5f and no other values. It's not specific to any particular ogg file. I do know it changes the pitch during playback in soundmanager. Since no one else answered, I figured my answer might be better than no answer.

Comment: I know I am late (maybe it was different back then), but currently it can be value between 0.5 - 2.0, as written in the Android API, "float: playback rate (1.0 = normal playback, range 0.5 to 2.0)"  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#play(int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float)