# How to change frequency of audio file and save it as mp4 file on sdcard?

Tags: android, audio, frequency

I m trying to make an app where user can record his voice and can play the voice in funny tone. Like talking tom application but not just that..He shd be able to share that recorded sound file.
I m able to record the sound but not able to save the file in funny tone..its getting saved in original tone.
any suggestions?

```
private void startRecording() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.mp4";
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);

    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737636/changing-the-frequency-of-a-soundfile-in-android

Comment: I want to save the file as changed pitch.

Comment: have you solved this problem?