# How to change frequency of audio using java

Tags: java, android, audio, core-audio, audio-streaming

How to change the frequency of audio sound clip using java. and what kind of api's can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has an answer here [Changing Pitch and Frequency of Recorded Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992943/changing-pitch-and-frequency-of-recorded-audio)

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(size, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mSoundPoolMap.put(index, mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.sound, 1));


mSoundPool.play(id, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, loop, 1f);
```

The frequency is the 1f part. If you change it to a value between .5f and 2.0f that should slow down or speed up the sample, which changes the pitch.

Taken from:
[Changing Pitch and Frequency of Recorded Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992943/changing-pitch-and-frequency-of-recorded-audio)