# How to sperate frequency from recorded voice -- Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm finding out for a solution to separate a specific frequency from a recorded voice. For ex, I have a recorded voice with 600Hz , and I want to extract only 300Hz  frequency from that recorded voice.  I'm new to this frequency set of questions, pl suggest me a valid solutions. Thanks in advance

Comment: i think this will help you to understand what you want to do:[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992943/changing-pitch-and-frequency-of-recorded-audio)

Comment: Thanks for quick response,  is it possible to extract that particular frequency voice and convert into separate mp3 file?